# What does "all your ties are bending, breaking" mean in "I Can't Save the World If I'm Not Happy"?

Tags: song-lyrics, eliza-grace

<sub>**CW**: mentions of self-harm.</sub>

---

Eliza Grace's song "[I Can't Save the World If I'm Not Happy](https://genius.com/Eliza-grace-i-cant-save-the-world-if-im-not-happy-lyrics)" is quite obviously a song about depression; there are several mentions of self-harm ("you can't calm your wrists with a razor blade") and the whole song has a very depressed feel to it.

The outro of the song (that's a bit hard to hear if you're not paying attention) goes like this:

> And I've been noticing all your ties are bending, breaking
>   Because you've been thinking you're not happy anymore

What does that line "all your ties are bending, breaking" mean? What does "ties" mean here, and in what way are they bending and breaking?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with actual depression.

I see no indication in the lyrics that "ties" would mean anything but "relationships".

I would take "your ties are bending, breaking" to mean: when you are depressed, the relationships ("ties") you have to other people are under stress. These others may feel they need to treat you differently because of your depression; they will feel the need to strain to keep up their relationship with you ("bending"). They may even give up altogether ("breaking").

It does take a lot of effort to maintain a relationship with someone who's not happy, and there are many do's and don'ts.